# Can Dialogflow agents be created, updated and deleted (managed) 100% programmatically?

Tags: automation, bots, dialogflow-es

I am looking to wrap a bot service in order to enable business areas to create and manage them at will with minimal technical knowledge, but meeting our strict security controls.  With this in mind I need to be able to create and manage them 100% programatically.

I have been working on a prototype with Microsoft's Bot Framework, Luis and QnA Maker.  Sadly though joining these technologies requires a number of manual steps, specifically:

- Creating a bot in Azure (Bot Framework)
- Creating a Luis Account
- Joining Luis bot with Azure(the subscription management part
  of the API was recently deprecated)
- Creating a QnA Account

Microsoft really don't feel very joined up at all...

With this in mind I am now looking for alternatives and thus looking to see what Google are up to.  I am just a bit weary of heading off in a new direction to find similar issues.

Looking briefly at the API documentation it seems I should be able to import an agent in to a project and then manage it.  I imagine I could use a template to create my bots from.

Thanks for your time

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Quick Update, in the end we went with a solution based on this idea:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-question-and-answer-bot-with-amazon-lex-and-amazon-alexa/

I can simply create a new bot by executing cloudformation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback.

The way I see it, Bot Framework is more modular than other options out there. First of all, creating a LUIS and QnA account are optional and not time consuming. The average use case can be solved with less than 50 lines of code with no need to throw LUIS or QnAMaker into the mix. Why should Microsoft force you to use LUIS if you might not need it? Google uses a different approach. In my opinion, they give you most of the tools from start, like the NLP agent, so you need to understand NLP concepts even if you don't really need to use them. Most developers tend to overthink their bots and make them more complex that hey need to be.

With that said. We don't provide a way to create agents programmatically. But the process of registering your bot is very straight forward and fast. Let me know if you have any problems on this regard.

Please, take a look at our samples here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples
They can give you a very deep knowledge on what architecture to use for different scenarios. Many times there is a simpler way to achieve the same goal and Microsoft does not try to force you to use the most advanced techniques. Most of the time you can achieve your goal with very simple and easy to maintain code.

Francisco

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was pretty happy with Microsoft's offerings, but deployment automation (including bot creation) is a must for me.  Also the convoluted way of joining to Azure accounts did't feel at all Customer centric, but I see it is moving somewhat in the right direction with the recent changes to Bot Framework (although currently lacking the automation part).  I will keep an eye on the products and pick and choose as needed.